# Editing the style of chapters, sections, subsections, etc and add a chapter outline, along with a brief content section

Tags: environments, theorems, preamble

I found [this](https://assets.openstax.org/oscms-prodcms/media/documents/AlgebraAndTrigonometry-OP_1tE6R5r.pdf) Algebra and Trigonometry crash course pdf, and I really like the style.

Could someone give me tips or links to websites that teach you how to create chapters, sections, subsections, etc?

Also, how do you create the chapter outline? Is there a command, or do I have to create it?
For the Brief Contents and Table of Contents, the Brief Contents just gives you a summary of all the chapters, and the Table of Contents gives you a list of all the chapters, sections, subsections, etc. I know how to create the Table of Contents. You use the `\tableofcontents` command, but how do I create the Brief Contents?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you more interested in the colors and fonts than the content?  Theoretically one could do \tableofcontents twice with different \tocdepth values.  See the multitoc package.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm interested in the colors and fonts because Tom already gave me information on how to create the tableofcontents.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this without package is probably create another `toc` file (e.g. `*.btoc`) by define a new command `\brieftoc`. And patch the `\@chapter` command to add only chapter entries to `*.btoc`. Then you can print the brief contents table using command `\brieftoc`. Other options you could take a look `minitoc`, `tocloft`, `titletoc` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\brieftoc{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\bcontentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\bcontentsname}{\MakeUppercase\bcontentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{btoc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\chaptermark{#1}}{\addcontentsline
{btoc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}\chaptermark{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\bcontentsname}{Brief Contents}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\begin{document}
\brieftoc
\tableofcontents
\duckument
\duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's really cool. I never heard of the duckuments before. Anyway, thanks a lot. You've saved me a ton of time!

Comment: @SingularisArt You are welcome! Yep, duckuments create some fake document. I feel interesting as well when I first heard about it.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how I can create those fancy-looking environments, do you?

Comment: @SingularisArt You mean the example and solution in the figures?

Comment: Yeah. I'm a little new to latex, and I have no idea where to start.

Comment: @SingularisArt You could take a look the `amsthm` package